# HTML5 canvas drawing is slower in Cocoa WebView than Safari

Tags: javascript, macos, canvas, safari, webview

I'm trying to build a wrapper app using WebView for HTML5 game that uses canvas for drawing.
In Safari I'm getting 60fps but in WebView inside a wrapper app fps drops significantly (to 30-45).

Is canvas slower in WebView than Safari or I'm doing something wrong?
If so, why and can anything be done about it?

I have searched the Web for answer but can't find any mention of speed difference.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not talking about iOS but OSX.

Comment: Probably Canvas is hardware accelerated in Safari but not in WebView (`citation needed`)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, haven't found the answer to my question but have solved my problem.
I circumvented WebViews canvas drawing slowness by not using WebView.

I rather built a wrapper for my game using JavaScriptCore framework and redirected canvas calls to OpenGL functions. Also redirected audio calls to OpenAL, and mouse input from view to JavaScript.

Game code haven't changed a bit, and engine (small, custom one) got a few function overrides.

Comment: very interesting solution. Can this work without modifying the HTML/js? Is it a drop-in replacement? If so, can you open source it for others to enjoy ?